# laptop screen flickers and goes blank

Tags: laptop, lcd

My laptop screen flickers and goes black. I can hear start up music in the background so i know there is something wrong with the display. I am confused if i should try to replace LCD Inverter or Backlight?

Any idea on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This community is a place to answer **programming** questions.

Comment: @Kirk: I agree, you have the rep to move it to Super User?

Comment: sorry abt that.

Answer (score 1):

Shine a torch on the black screen, and get someone with VERY good eyesight to see if they can see anything on the screen. It will be REALLY dark and hard to see the image, but it's it's there, then it's your LCD Backlight Inverter, a very typical malfunction. They are $20+ to buy, and takes an hour or so of semi-skilled electronics engineering to perform. Danger: you are dealing with 10,000v and could threaten life. Pay $60 for a shop to replace the inverter.

Comment: 10,000v? I think if i un-plug the laptop and remove the battery before replacing the interter, there will be no power. Isnt it?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Capacitors can hold a charge for a very long time.  Also, if you cannot see the image with a bright flashlight, the problem could be the panel itself, or a bad video card.

Comment: I have never heard that the inverter in an LCD display could be dangerous. Do you have a citation for this assertion? Voltage of 10,000V alone is not an indication of danger. 10,000V is less than what you typically generate with static electricity.

Comment: 10,000 volts??? seriously? that is the about what you see on low level power lines, not LCD inverters. An LCD inverter will have about 500-700 v AC output at most, which is still a lot, but considering the amperage would be fairly low, it would definitely not be life threatening, but could give a bit of a shock if you aren't careful. Now if the amperage were equally as high, you'd have to worry, but with so little juice going through that, the difference in force of the electrons makes little difference. As an example, police tasers give out about 1,200 volts, but the amperage is minimal.

Comment: Not life threatening but may give you a short jolt similar to what you get from static off your car.  10000V perhaps, but very very low current.